# Multiple File Issue

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I've encountered a unique issue with *Model View Controller* project, the issue occurs within a *Shared Layout*. I've got several Scripts & Style Sheet imported.

```
    <!-- Script: -->
    <script src="../../content/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Scripts/Navigation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Stylesheet: -->
    <link href="~/Content/Stylesheet/Skin.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Stylesheet/Navigation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

So I have related *Navigation* data in the `Navigation.css` that will handle particular layouts, then in the `Navigation.js` it will handle particular modifications to the root layout by adding particular elements like so:

```
$(function () {
     if(screen.width < 768 || screen.width < 1024) {
         $("nav").addClass(".Desktop-Navigation");
     }
});
```

But it seems to ignore the code when it is in a separate file.  It doesn't even if I contain the root either, however the code works correctly in *http://jsfiddle.net*.

I'm not sure the issue or cause.

I forgot to mention that I have indeed tried the following:

- I've tried doing `$(document).ready`
- Moving scripts to be last item loaded on page.

The code above the `addClass` always executes, but the `addClass` portion never actually executes.  This is the code above that always executes:

```
$(function () {
     $("#Toggle-Menu").click( function () {
          $("nav").animate({ height: 'toggle' }, 500);
     });
});
```

Is this an issue with how Model View Controller renders it Views, why is this happening?

Comment: Look at generated HTML ("view source" in browser) and check if path to JS makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your JavaScript is executing before your HTML is fully rendered.  This is reinforced by the fact that your jsfiddle is probably configured to execute on document ready.  As a result, trying wrapping your function is a doc ready as well.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(screen.width < 768 || screen.width < 1024) {
        $("nav").addClass(".Desktop-Navigation");
    }
});
```

Comment: I did try that, still didn't impact it though. Quite peculiar.

Comment: Does your Navigation.js code ever get hit if you place a breakpoint inside?  In addition, have you verified that the script actually pulls down?